# When I going to print a hexadecimal value using printf it takes the input as decimal value why?

Tags: c, hex, printf, conversion-specifier

For example

```
printf("%x",16);
```

This printf prints 10 instead of 16 why it is not take the value as hexadecimal pls someone explain this

Comment: 16 decimal is 10 hex.

Answer (score 3):

`16` is a decimal integer constant. Thus the hexadecimal representation of the constant is `10`. If you want to specify a hexadecimal integer constant then write `0x16u`. Pay attention to that the conversion specifier `x` expects an argument of the type `unsigned int`. So the suffix `u` is used in the hexadecimal integer constant.

So the call of `printf` can look like

```
printf( "%x\n", 0x16u );
```

and the output will be `16`.

Or

```
printf( "%#x\n", 0x16u );
```

and the output will be `0x16`.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a number to a function, you are not passing decimal or hexadecimal. Conceptually, you are passing a value, an abstract mathematical number.

That number is represented in some *type*, and C uses binary to represent values in integer types (along with some supplement of binary for signed numbers, usually two’s complement).

Whether you write `printf("%x\n", 16u)` or `printf("%x\n", 0x10u);`, the compiler converts that numeral in source code, `16u` or `0x10u`, to an `unsigned int` value, represented in binary. It is that resulting value that is passed to `printf`, not a decimal “16” or a hexadecimal “10”.

(I use `16u` and `0x10u` rather than `16` or `0x10` because `printf` expects an `unsigned int`, not an `int`.)

The `%x` directive tells `printf` to expect an `unsigned int` value and to **convert** it to a hexadecimal numeral. So the original input form is irrelevant; `%x` means to produce hexadecimal regardless of the original form.